# Siblings pure JavaScript with show and hide, now jQuery

Tags: javascript

What is the best way of achieving this, vanilla JavaScript.
I really want to understand it.
Thanks so much.

```
 $(duplicate[ii]).hide().siblings().show();
```

Comment: Implement it one by one. First `hide()`. Then fetch siblings. Then show all of them. Stackoverflow is not a free jquery->native DOM code conversion service.

Comment: It's complicated, if you're talking about the easing and everything. Simply put, you just look over the `Element.childNodes` making sure `Element.childNodes[increment].nodeType === 1` and effect `Element.childNodes[increment].style.opacity = opacityIncrement`. To be backward compatible you effect `Element.childNodes[increment].style.filter = 'alpha(opacity='+alphaIncrement+')'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `duplicate[ii]` is a DOM element, you could loop the children of the parent of that element, and set the style of the actual element after the loop.

```
const d = duplicate[ii];

for (const el of d.parentNode.children) {
  el.style.display = "block";
}
d.style.display = "none";
```

---

However, while that's basically a translation, I wouldn't write it that way. I'd use classes with the appropriate styling:

```
const d = duplicate[ii];

for (const el of d.parentNode.querySelectorAll(".hide")) {
  el.classList.remove("hide");
}
d.classList.add("hide");
```

---

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

---

If you know only one element will have `hide` at any given time, you can drop the loop.

```
const h = duplicate[ii].parentNode.querySelector(".hide")
if (h) {
  h.classList.remove("hide");
}
duplicate[ii].classList.add("hide");
```

---

If you do this frequently, I'd create a utility function that receives a class name, an element, and a collection. You could even enhance it so that the collection is optional, in which case you'd use the siblings.

```
function swapClass(clss, target, els) {
    if (!els) {
      els = target.parentNode.children;
    }

    for (const el of els) {
      el.classList.remove(cls);
    }
    target.classList.add(cls);
}
```

Then its just like this:

```
swapClass("hide", duplicate[ii]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const toArray = (list) => Array.prototype.slice.call(list)

const foo = (node) => {
    let children = toArray(node.parentNode.children)
    children.forEach(child => {
        child.style.display = child === node ? 'none' : 'block'
    })
}
```

If `duplicate[ii]` is a DOM , just `foo(duplicate[ii])`

If `duplicate[ii]` is a Css Selector, you can use

```
toArray(document.querySelectorAll(selector)).forEach(node => {
    foo(node)
})
```

This answer is assuming node is is `Block` element